# How to filter data in searchController using Share Class in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I am using `UISearchController` to filter data. Here is my code:

```
var filteredData: [ShareObj] = [ShareObj]()
     var arrHotelData : [ShareObj] = [ShareObj]()


extension AddAddressVC : UISearchResultsUpdating {

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {

        filteredData.removeAll()

        let type2Array = arrHotelData.filter { $0.strHotelName == searchText.lowercased()}

        print(type2Array)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

Here is my code to save data

```
   for  i in 0..<arrData.count
                {
                    let ShareObj : ShareObj = AddHotelShareObj()
                    let dict = arrData[i]

                    if (dict[""]) != nil {
                        ShareObj.strHotelName = dict[""] as! String
                     }

                    if (dict[""]) != nil {
                        ShareObj.strAddress = dict[""] as! String
                    }

                    if (dict[""]) != nil {
                        ShareObj.strZipCode = dict[""] as! String
                    }

                  self.arrHotelData.append(ShareObj)
```

But array is returning []. Can you help me why it's not working

Comment: That's just initialization. That will return that only. Where are you assigning data to them ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan please check my updated question

Comment: show code of cellForRowAt

Comment: @iParesh its simply data get on condition.my question is my filter is not working. type2Array is returning blank

Comment: You code is not at all connected. Where are you assigning data to arrData ? arrData has any data ? Try to print addHotelShareObj before appending it and check if its not empty. And what is dict[""] ?

Comment: @SharadChauhan hello data is displaying in tableview.  searchbar is not working.

Comment: you are reloading you table view but i don't see any global array which is getting changed before tableView.reloadData() other than filteredData.removeAll() which will make it empty only. type2Array is empty ?

Comment: yes type2 array is empty

Comment: and you are typing full strHotelName which is present in Model ? It will work only if you type exact word.

Comment: @SharadChauhan yes strHotelName is object in my model class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171006/discussion-between-sharad-chauhan-and-kd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {

            filteredData.removeAll()

            let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains[c] %@", argumentArray: [searchText])

            let type2Array = self.arrHotelData.filter { filterPredicate.evaluate(with: $0.strHotelName) }
            print(type2Array)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredArray.removeAll()
    filteredArray = arrHotelData.filter({$0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here you should use `filteredData` to display and replace the code

`let ShareObj : ShareObj = AddHotelShareObj()` to 
`let shareObj : ShareObj = AddHotelShareObj()` because same reference and Type may cause problem.